# javascript functions within (document).ready() dont execute

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    'use strict';
    console.log('main.js loaded');
  
    //showtable();
    function showtable() {
    console.log("We are in the showtable function in main.js");
    let people = [
        {name:"Mohinder", gender: "Male", Age: 57},
        {name:"Rekha", gender: "Female", Age: 58},
        {name:"Karan", gender: "Male", Age: 30},
        {name:"Angad", gender: "Male", Age: 20},
        {name:"Reba", gender: "Female", Age: 10}
    ];
    var theDiv = document.getElementById("people");

    var tableString = "";
    tableString += "<table border=1 id='peopleTable' >";
    tableString += "<tr class='hdr'><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr>";
    for (var x = 0; x < people.length; x += 1)
        tableString += "<tr><td>" + people[x].name + "</td><td>" + people[x].Age + "</td></tr>";
        tableString += "</table>";
        theDiv.innerHTML += tableString;
    };
 
    function frontAndCenter() {
         console.log("We are in the frontAndCenter function in main.js");
        var rtnval = '' ;
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('table');
        if (x[0].className)
         x[0].className = "raise";
        else
            x[0].className+="raise";
     return rtnval;
    }
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */
.raise{
 box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px green ;
 margin: auto ;
}
#mainCanvas{
 width: 400px;
 height:400px;
 border: solid 1px black;
}
.hdr {
    background-color:cyan;
}
td {
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
        <title>Learning JS</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <h1> My first application! </h1>
  <p id="people"></p>
        <button id='peopleBtn' onclick="showtable();">Show People Table</button>
        <button id='daBtn' onclick="frontAndCenter();">Click Me</button>
  <script src="main_funs.js"></script>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <script src="main2.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I am a total newbie so please bear with me.
I have this small app that I wrote while learning JS. It contains a function to create a table of people names and ages that is invoked by a button click.
Then there is another function that adds a class to the table which then is modified (display wise) by the CSS in effect and this is also invoked by the click of another button.
I have put all JS within a file encapsulated in $(document).ready(){....}
what I notice is that the functions don't execute. 
I then added the functions to another JS file without the (document).ready(){....} and those functions execute as expected.
I tried the same with window.onload(){.....} also and they don't execute either.
Can someone shed some light on this please? 
Not sure if I can attach files here or not but the code is pasted above. The button clicks will not work. But if you copy the functions to another file and name it main_funs.js the code will work.
Sorry did my best to convey the problem I am having but if it is not clear please let me know and I can send you the code files.
Thanks

main.html

Comment: You are trying to load the same version of jQuery twice.  Remove the `<script>` tag that is before your document.

Comment: @jfriend00 that is not part of my code. I guess when I was adding the code to be posted in my question I must have clicked on something and that got added. I am assuming that is what happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you have defined the functions in the `$(document).ready()` handler, so they are out of the scope of the `on*` event attributes (which rely on the functions being globally available).

To fix this you can move your functions out of the `$(document).ready()` handler, or better yet, use unobtrusive Javascript to attach your events and keep it all within the handler.

As you're already using jQuery, here's an example of how to do that:

```
<button id="peopleBtn">Show People Table</button>
<button id="daBtn">Click Me</button>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';

    $('#peopleBtn').click(function() {
        console.log("We are in the showtable function in main.js");
        let people = [{ /* your objects ... */ }];
        var $div = $("#people");
        var tableString = '<table border="1" id="peopleTable"><tr class="hdr"><td>Name</td><td>Age</td></tr>';    
        for (var x = 0; x < people.length; x += 1)
            tableString += '<tr><td>' + people[x].name + '</td><td>' + people[x].Age + '</td></tr>';
        tableString += '</table>';
        $("#people").html(tableString);
    });

    $('#daBtn').click(function() {
        console.log("We are in the frontAndCenter function in main.js");
        $('table:first').addClass('raise');
    })
});
```

Note that I also tidied the logic slightly by using some of jQuery's methods.

Comment: Thanks Rory for a super quick response. Will mark your answer as "Accepted". Cannot do it yet I am being asked to wait 8 minutes??!!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Also, see jfriend's comment on your question about the placement of your scripts. You appear to be including jQuery twice, and one of those is in the incorrect place and should be removed.